# Blender smoothed everything

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender and started to create a low-poly character. I was working on the hands when suddenly Blender smoothed everything out. I googled a bit but i couldn't really find a solution to this. I wanted to extrude and i don't know what i accidently pressed but this happned:
[image]

How can i undo this ?

Comment: Welcome to blender.SE! Did you try to undo the operation? What happened? Could you show the modifier panel?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. You probably added a subdivision surface modifier by accident. It will appear in the Modifier panel, as Carlo mentioned. It could have been added by pressing Ctrl + 1 or Ctrl + 2. To "reset" it with a shortcut, press Ctrl + 0.

Comment: as Leander has said you are to remove the subdivision modifier. To do it, just select the object, then go to the properties window, the tab with a wrench icon. You have your modifiers there. Delete or disable them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did u accidentally add a modifier? if that's the case remove it.
If that's not the case then try decimating its geometry.
To decimate: Properties -> Modifiers. Then click on Add modifier and select Decimate\
hopefully, that should work

Comment: Actually there was a modifier added like you said. I removed it and everything is normal now although i do not know how i added a modifier with a hotkey.

Comment: your welcome :D